# Flask SQLAlchemy - StaticMethod vs Custom Querying Class

Tags: python, flask, model, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an `Event` Model with both `start_date` and `due_date` columns.
I want to create an easy way to get all active events (which have been already started but not finished yet).

This is my Event model class:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(254))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    due_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

---

I familiar with two working solutions for this need:

1: With a `staticmethod` function which will make all filters on the Event.query object and return a complete list of active events

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def get_active():
         return Event.query.filter(...).all()

# Usage:
records = Event.get_active()
```

2: By creating a new query object that inherits from `BaseQuery`, and assign this new "EventQuery" class to the Model's `query_class` member.

```
class EventQuery(BaseQuery):
    def get_active(self):
        return self.filter(...)

class Event(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    query_class = EventQuery
    ....

# Usage:
Event.query.get_active().all()
```

So I'm wondering, which method is better/recommended ?

Comment: By what metric? 1 is probably more straightforward, and easier to maintain

Comment: I saw a lot of people here recommend on creating custom query class as I showed in the second way, so i wandered if there is an actual reason for this... Surely the first way is simpler so why there is so many documentations on this "unnecessary" custom querying feature?

Answer (score 4):

For a simple isolated example I don't think it matters much. For larger more complex cases, option 2 offers additional flexibility to combine your filter with other filters.

`Event.query.filter_by(user_id=1).get_active().all()`

Admittedly you could modify option 1 so that it takes a query as an argument and returns a new query, but then it would start looking rather different than typical SQLAlchemy queries.